# When replacing a laptop screen, can only the right OEM screens be used?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

Suppose we try to install a screen of the wrong brand (e.g. one that is smaller or equal to the correct size). Suppose further that we somehow beat the mechanical/physical connection aspect of it into submission.

What would it take to make it work on the electronic and software level?

For example, would I need to replace the driver (or some software equivalent for screens)? Is the VGA interface the same in both cases? What other issues could occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectors will probably be the most difficult issue. I've taken apart several different types of laptops and their connectors tended to be different in each case.

If you can get around the connector issue, there should not be any real issues from the driver/software/video card. The monitor has it's own drivers which will tell the video card what sort of resolution and frequency the screen can communicate at.

Comment: is that power connector? or VGA connector? are there any other connector types involved?

Comment: In most laptops I have looked at the power and video are integrated in the same connector. However, I'd imagine that is not always the case. These connectors are an easy thing for companies to make different to make it difficult to swap screens, such as you're doing.